# Scraping a HTML table in R, after changing a Javascript dropdown option

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am looking to scrape the main table from [this website](https://www.futbin.com/19/players). I have managed to get the table into R and working, but the one problem is the website defaults to PS4, while I wanted the data for Xbox (this is changed in the top-right dropdown menu).

Ideally there would be a way to pass a parameter in the URL that will define the platform in this way, but I haven't been able to find anything about that.

Looking around it seems that PhantomJS would be the best way to go but I have no experience using Javascript and I'm not sure how you would implement performing an action on the page, then scraping the resulting table.

This is currently all I have in terms of my main code scraping the data:

```
library(rvest)
url1 <- "https://www.futbin.com/19/players?page="
pge <- 1
tbl <- paste0(url1, pge) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="repTb"]') %>%
  html_table()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.